# How to redirect back to Create page after Authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, backend, .net-8.0

This should be an easy fix. I have an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project with a `Create` page, where any user can access and use the tools on the page, but cannot save their work without logging in. User management is handled by Identity.

Currently, if a user is not logged in and clicks save, they are redirected to the login page. However, upon logging in, the user is taken back to the `Create` page, but with no fields populated. Additionally there is no record saved to the database.

I would like the fields to remain populated when the user returns to the `Create` page after logging in.

I haven't tried much to fix this because I'm new and I'm not sure where to start. I would guess that maybe I could put the data in some temp storage such as tempdata. Maybe there is also something I could do in the login and registration controllers.

Thanks in advance for any advice and let me know if you'd like me to include my code.

EDIT -------------

OP Here. Here's where I ended up.

Assuming `Obj` is my form data and `val` is the label of some text within the form, in my `[Get] Create` method, I have:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        // if session data for val is set, get the val and create a new Obj
        if (!HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyObjVal).IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            Obj prepopulatedObj = new Obj()
            {
                val = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyObjVal)
            };
            // reset session data to empty after use
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyDescription, ""); 

            // return view with fields populated based on session data
            return View(prepopulatedObj);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And in my `[Post] Create` method I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Obj obj)
    {
        // if not authenticated, set session data for val and redirect to login
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("val", Obj.val);
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity" });
        }
        etc...
```

Which works!!!! However, because I am not using `[Authorize]` on my `Post` method, the user is redirected to the home page after logging in. Please let me know if anyone has some alternate approaches. I can't think of any way to ensure that the user is taken to the `Create` page after login in this specific case

EDIT 2 -----------

I changed the redirect to `return Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FTabs%2FCreate");` in the `Post` `Create` method and it now works.

Comment: You could address this the complicated way, by saving the session state and rehydrating it once the user returns to the page. Wouldn't it be simpler, though, to immediately require that the user logs in when (s)he first requests the `Create` page? That is, before entering any data?

Comment: You are now having an MVC project, so that when we want to render a form with init data in it, we can do what is similar to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-8.0), which will `return View(data)`, the data we need to store in somewhere and send them when redirect to the Create page.

Comment: I think you're fixing the wrong problem. If a user is not logged it, they shouldn't be able to see the page they can fill-in data.

Comment: @MarkSeemann In my case I'm creating a tool for the user, where they may or may not have the need to save their work.

Comment: Reloading the Create page with fields to remain populated requires us to return the data manually or fill the fields via js, which method you'd like to use?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need an event handler to Save input data. Maybe ValueChanged or OnSubmit
2. You should store input data into Local Storage. (Session can expire)
3. After postback, you can retrieve data from Local Storage and fill the form.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply. I have gone with storing the data in `Session` storage and have some code that I think will work. Now I need to save the data when `Submit` is clicked on the form, but before `Post` is Authorised. I assume I would have some external C# file with a method that is called OnClick, but I'm not sure where the correct place to put the file is, and how to call the method. Let me know if you have any advice.